# Display NSAttributedString using a CATextLayer in Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios6, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring, catextlayer

I'm using a CATextLayer to render an NSAttributedString. When done in this method the color does not render correctly. When done using CTStringAttributes the color works, but the NSAttributedString does not know its own size. This is the code I'm using:

```
    var caTextLayer = new CATextLayer (); 
    var attributedString = new NSAttributedString
    ( 
            "test string",
            ForegroundColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor,
            Font = new CTFont ("Arial", 24),
            KerningAdjustment = 72f
    );


    caTextLayer.AttributedString = attributedString;
    caTextLayer.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    caTextLayer.ContentsScale = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;

    myViewController.View.Layer.InsertSublayer(layer3, 1);

    caTextLayer.SetNeedsDisplay ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CTStringAttributes if you are using CoreText layers

Comment: CTStringAttributes will present other issues. Link below as the NSAttributedString will not be able to know its own size. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814420/cannot-access-string-size-after-setting-ctstringattributes-font